# postgresql - can't create database - OperationalError: source database "template1" is being accessed by other users

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I logged in to source database template1 and now I can't create database.
When I try to create database, I get this error:

```
OperationalError: source database "template1" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 5 other session(s) using the database.
```

Every time I login to template1, I use 'exit' command to logout, but as you can see it does not logout and number of sessions increases everytime I login. Is there a way to force disconnect every connection to template1 that logged in now?

Comment: There is no `exit` command in `psql`. The command to leave `psql` is `\q` (and you shouldn't log in/use the template database in the first place)

Comment: I had to log in, because I needed to drop schema public and recreate it to fix one bug.

Comment: Also thanks for reply. Now it does not increase in logged in users count, but it stays as 5 users connected. How to force quit these connections?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This helped me solve my problem:

```
SELECT *, pg_terminate_backend(procpid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE usename='username';

--Use pid if PostgreSQL version 9.2 or above.
```

I terminated all active connections to template1 and could create database normally

Comment: 9.3 tells me `column "procpid" does not exist`

Comment: @dan-klasson use `pid`

Comment: So @Soumya how did you terminated the active connections?

Comment: @Andrius can u tell us what happened after this query.

Comment: Amazing solution.

Comment: Very good suggestion, but note that, **IF** you have tools like pgadmin running and connected, they *can* sometimes ignore this type of fix.  A server restart, which is "more powerful", did not fix it for me, you have to adjust/shut off pgadmin.

Answer (score 52):

Database [`template1`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html) exists only to provide barebone structure to create another empty database. You should *never* logon to `template1`, otherwise you will have problems.

Probably easiest solution for you is to restart PostgreSQL server process, and logon again. Database that should always exist and is safe to logon is `postgres`.

If restarting is not an option, you can use another emergency template database: `template0`.

By default, this statement:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

is equivalent to:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname TEMPLATE template1;
```

If `template1` is not available or corrupted, you can use `template0` as last resort:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname TEMPLATE template0;
```

You can read more about template databases [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html).

Comment: I didn't want to log in, but our ERP support told us to do it, to fix one bug..:)

Comment: From doc link: CREATE DATABASE will fail if any other connection to template1 exists. You can use last resort `template0`: `CREATE DATABASE dbname TEMPLATE template0`

Comment: In older Postgres version there was one reason to log onto the template database: create the plpgsql language in there so that every new database would automatically get it.

Comment: So there is no way to clear connections from template1? (I don't have permissions to restart postgresql server, so I asked for our server providers to do that, but its in pending state now)

Comment: You should be able to clear them by disconnecting. But, note that template databases are NOT supposed to have any connections, almost ever. If you use `template0`, you don't really need `template1`. I think this is probably the reason why there are 2 template databases - for situations like yours.

Comment: I create database using Openerp, so it creates database using template1.

Comment: What if you create empty database manually (using `psql` or `PgAdmin`), and then handoff this to OpenERP? It should be able to detect that this database is empty, and create necessary tables by itself?

Comment: I'll try. Also I wanted to ask, is using CTRL+C do not logout from template1? Because in terminal it show as I logged out, but in reality it stayed logged in and messed it like it is now.

Comment: If you talking about `psql`, right way to quit is `\q` <enter>.  BTW, if you really dropped public schema from `template1`, I think it is safe to say that `template1` is now **completely hosed**. You will likely need to recover `template1` by copying it from `template0`.

Comment: I tried to create db using template0, but I can't use that database in openerp. It says that database already exists

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22886/discussion-between-mvp-and-oerp)

Answer (score 18):

You can also try to terminate the current process thread by the Terminal

**Search the Process :**

```
sudo ps aux | grep template1
```

**Kill the Process :**

sudo kill -9 < your process id >

Comment: Which one is the PID?

Comment: @MarkA, 2nd column

Answer (score 13):

To solve this, I have to disconnect the database connection from the
pgAdmin III.

Answer (score 10):

I have a script that connects to a database and performs various operations on it, some requiring that no one else is logged in.  I modified @Andrius's answer not to terminate my script's connection, but rather terminate everyone else's:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

From the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-info.html): `pg_backend_pid()` is the Process ID of the server process attached to the current session.

Answer (score 6):

1. enter pgAdmin
2. right-click to server
3. disconnect server
4. again connect server
5. do what you want

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the PgAdminn, you can manually set the definitions provided in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to kill all the connections to the template database and leave other connections uninterrupted, so use the following query to kill all the connections to templateDb

```
    SELECT 
    pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM 
    pg_stat_activity 
WHERE 
    -- don't kill my own connection!
    pid <> pg_backend_pid()
    -- don't kill the connections to other databases
    AND datname = 'templateDb'
    ;
```

Then use the usual query to copy the templateDb

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname TEMPLATE templateDb ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem occur when you had logged(**psql template1** or **psql template0**) in template1 and template0 database and exit using below command.

**Ctrl + z**

Better way exist from db use below postgres command then problem will not create:

**\q + enter**

There are 2 solutions, If have problem.

**Solution - 1**

Restart posgres service like.

sudo service postgresql restart

**Solution - 2**

sudo ps aux | grep template1

**Make sure don't delete this processes**

postgres  8363  0.0  0.0 111760  7832 pts/11   T    09:49   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/psql template1
ankit    18119  0.0  0.0  14224   976 pts/14   S+   12:33   0:00 grep --color=auto template1

rest of process should be kill using below command.

sudo kill -9

Now try to create db again.

Hope this help you.

Ankit H Gandhi.

Comment: what worked for me on a mac: `brew services restart postgresql`

Answer (score 1):

If you use **pgadmin4** or similar tools, makes sure it is either doing the `create database` itself or that it's shut off.

I had generated a `create database` with pgadmin4 then used its scripting functionality to export the script it used, which I then copied and altered to put it in my own automated scripts.

Problem was that the active webpage pgadmin somehow ended up on database `template1`.

Stopping and restarting the server itself didn't fix anything, pgadmin was smart enough to reconnect to the server as soon as it came back up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart the postgresql service that is running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I had to reinstall PostgreSQL, restart did not help.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the side panel , browser, servers, database, then on the right is a summary of the database...becareful here, there is a  press right and find the dropdown to delete the database, so if sure, get rid of existing database, and create a new one, so that you can claim ownership of the newly created one

Answer (score 0):

In windows. shutdown the GUI. do it from psql command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem but after googling, I understood I have a connection to (**postgis_30_sample**) database (the template that I want to copy from). This connection was created by **GeoServer** when I created some stores in Geo Server application.

So I Stopped the service and the issue was fixed !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem like this via reconnecting to the server (pgAdmin -> disconnect -> connect)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with:
ERROR: source database "template1" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL: There is 1 other session using the database.

And i Solved the problem in postgreSQL 13 by clicking in the left column on PostgreSQL 13 where the tables showing some graphs appeared. I was interested in the sever activity table, here I found a line that contained the word template1 and I turned it off with a cross, then restarted the application here and everything works.

[error: template1-solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OutKK.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker, have to set host to '0.0.0.0' than 'localhost' in your sequelize config.

Comment: Where should this be set ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across almost same problem. Solution I found is--> "closed dbeaver GUI on my UBUNTU machine and used terminal to create database(lc_db1) using my other database(lc_db) as a TEMPLATE by using following command-->

```
    CREATE DATABASE lc_db1 TEMPLATE lc_db;
```

[Output of this code is:-->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUDrc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).