# copy tables/fields of postgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to create a new database with the same tables/fields as an existing database. I don't need any of the rows, I just need the schema. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808735/postgresql-how-to-create-a-copy-of-a-database-or-schema

Answer (score 1):

You can copy just the schema using pg_dump, then restore it in your new database.

```
pg_dump --schema-only
```

Comment: How would you create a new database with that schema?

Comment: @user1802143 Just use createdb to create a new database then pg_restore to restore the backup (which has only the schema) to that new database.

Comment: Provided both databases exist already you can do this in a single command. pg_dump oldDB --schema-only  | psql -h localhost newDB;