# Create a copy of db schema only psql

Tags: psql

I have db named "mydb". Now How can I create a new db with name "mydb_test" with only schema of "mydb"

Tried the following link [PostgreSQL how to create a copy of a database or schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808735/postgresql-how-to-create-a-copy-of-a-database-or-schema)

As mentioned over there I tried the following command,

```
createdb -T olddb newdb
```

This copies including the data into newdb

If I try the second option mentioned in the above link I get following error,

```
# pg_dump -Cs -U postgres my_test_db > dump_schema_file
# psql -U postgres naggappan_my_test_db < dump_schema_file
 psql: FATAL:  database "naggappan_my_test_db" does not exist
```

How can I take only schema

Answer (score 0):

- You may create a new dump without data of required schema and then restore from it into a new DB:

  `# pg_dump --dbname=source_db_name --username=postgres --encoding=UTF8 --schema=db_schema --schema-only --file=path_to_filename.dump`

  `# psql --dbname=target_db_name --username=postgres --file=path_to_filename.dump`
- If you have an existing dump with schema and/or data in *binary* format, you can restore only the schema from it using `pg_restore`:

  `# pg_restore --dbname=target_db_name --username=postgres --schema-only path_to_filename.dump`