# Clone database and it's tables structure to another database (without data)

Tags: postgresql

I have already known query to clone like:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_dest WITH TEMPLATE db_src OWNER postgres
```

But that query also cloned the data in the tables. I want to clone all tables and it's structures in the database, but not the data. How can I do this?

Comment: There is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808735/postgresql-how-to-create-a-copy-of-a-database-or-schema, using `pg_dump with the --schema-only option.`

Comment: @vitaly-t thank you, but there is no query for doing this?

Comment: @Giovanno: no, the way through a SQL dump without data is the best option you have. Alternatively clone the database, then truncate all tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Okay I see, thank you...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if is SQL comand for this. but you can try

create backoup in PGadmin and in dump option select only schema option and then restore it to new db.